# C# WinForms Loop through DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms

My application is a scheduler, build with an DataGridView.

I want to loop through a DateTimePicker and increase the days each time it loops through and add it into the DataGridView.
My actual problem is, that after i click on the add button, it puts x amounts of rows into my list, but not increasing the day. So i got X lines with the same date.

How it should work:
Pick a date, select the case from combobox list, interval gets added automatically.
Then the actual check if the interval is (daily/weekdays).
If i now click the button "add entrys", it adds the input into the datagridview.
Date / Case / Interval / Added by (from userprincipal).

Here is my actual code:

```
        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Add intervall
        {
            addIntervall();
            
        }
        void addIntervall()
        {           
            if (cbIntervall.Text == "daily")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    datePicker.Value.AddDays(1);
                    schedulerGrid.Rows.Add(datePicker.Text, cbCase.Text, cbIntervall.Text, lblUserDisplay.Text);
                }
            
            }
        }
```

My next step would be to add another step for "only within the week" so it would exclude the weekend days.

**EDIT**:
Just inserted the code from Enigmativity and it works fine!

```
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    DateTime value = datePicker.Value;
                    DateTime updated = value.AddDays(1);
                    schedulerGrid.Rows.Add(datePickerControl.Text, datePicker.Text, cbCase.Text, cbIntervall.Text, lblUserDisplay.Text);
                    datePicker.Value = updated;
                }
```

Comment: `but not increasing the day.` where you need to do this? In the grid view?

Comment: The gridview gets the date from the datetimepicker.
And everytime it loops through the method, it should increase by 1 day and after that, it should be added in the grid view. so lets say 06.08. -> 07.08 -> 08.08 and so on

Comment: After the loop execution the `datePicker` values changes to the 7 days later date?

Comment: But the "datePicker.Value.AddDays(1)" gets ignored and i only get 7 rows added into my list with the same date

Comment: After i click the add button, i get 7 rows with same date, but the picker only add +1 days when i click on the button. 
So technically it wont increase by itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `datePicker.Value.AddDays(1);` returns a new date. You're computing it and throwing the value away. It's as if you wrote this:

```
DateTime value = datePicker.Value
DateTime updated = value.AddDays(1);
```

You've just not done anything with `updated`.

You'd need this:

```
datePicker.Value = updated;
```

---

If it were me doing this I wouldn't rely on a control formatting your string for you. I'd separate building your rows from adding them to the  grid.

Try this:

```
void AddInterval()
{
    if (cbInterval.Text == "daily")
    {
        var rows =
            from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 7)
            let date = datePicker.Value.AddDays(i).ToString()
            select new
            {
                date,
                caseText = cbCase.Text,
                interval = cbInterval.Text,
                userDisplay = lblUserDisplay.Text,
            };
                
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            schedulerGrid.Rows.Add(
                row.date,
                row.caseText,
                row.interval,
                row.userDisplay);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh heck...was it really that simple?!
Just inserted it and it works!
Thank you very much!

Comment: That sounds interesting. I will give it a shot. Thank you!